# I want to send file more than 20mb to amazon s3 without using any app exchange app

Tags: integration, sales

I want to send files more than 20MB size to amazon s3 without using any app exchange app. can anyone suggest a better approach

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the [Amazon Multipart upload](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/mpuoverview.html) and then split the file into chunks and upload it partially.

Otherwise, and if you have the chance to work with an external system that does not have the same heap limitations as Salesforce, you can also send them the `VersionData` so that it can be queried and directly uploaded.